# MariaDB innodb_index_stats vs SHOW INDEXES result

Tags: mariadb, innodb

Is there any reason why mysql.innodb_index_stats would NOT match the result of SHOW INDEXES when innodb_stats_persistent=ON?

We have that turned on, and we’ve increased innodb_stats_persistent_sample_pages significantly, and see the correct result in mysql.innodb_index_stats, however SHOW INDEXES still returns a wildly different number for cardinality.

Are we missing something?

**UPDATE WITH MORE DETAIL:**

(Some fields renamed for privacy)

```
+---------------------------+
| @@innodb_stats_persistent |
+---------------------------+
|                         1 |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [TestDB]> OPTIMIZE TABLE itm_location ;
+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table               | Op       | Msg_type | Msg_text                                                          |
+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| TestDB.itm_location | optimize | note     | Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead |
| TestDB.itm_location | optimize | status   | OK                                                                |
+---------------------+----------+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (7.18 sec)

MariaDB [TestDB]> FLUSH TABLE itm_location ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)                

MariaDB [TestDB]> SHOW INDEX FROM itm_location ;
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name       | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Ignored |
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
| itm_location  |          0 | PRIMARY        |            1 | id             | A         |     1683506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| itm_location  |          0 | combo          |            1 | itm_id         | A         |     1683506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| itm_location  |          0 | combo          |            2 | location_id    | A         |     1683506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| itm_location  |          1 | location_id    |            1 | location_id    | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| itm_location  |          1 | location_id    |            2 | itm_id         | A         |     1683506 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
| itm_location  |          1 | qty            |            1 | qty            | A         |        1262 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               | NO      |
+---------------+------------+----------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [TestDB]> SELECT * FROM mysql.innodb_index_stats WHERE `database_name` LIKE 'TestDB' AND table_name = 'itm_location ';
+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| database_name | table_name    | index_name     | last_update         | stat_name    | stat_value | sample_size | stat_description                  |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
| TestDB        | itm_location  | PRIMARY        | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx01 |    1683506 |          20 | id                                |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | PRIMARY        | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_leaf_pages |      14267 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | PRIMARY        | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | size         |      16367 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | qty            | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx01 |        631 |           6 | qty                               |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | qty            | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx02 |    1696404 |          20 | qty,id                            |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | qty            | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_leaf_pages |       1516 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | qty            | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | size         |       1763 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | combo          | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx01 |     422730 |          20 | itm_id                            |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | combo          | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx02 |    1696410 |          20 | itm_id,location_id                |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | combo          | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_leaf_pages |       1830 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | combo          | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | size         |       2148 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | location_id    | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx01 |          3 |           5 | location_id                       |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | location_id    | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx02 |    1696410 |          20 | location_id,itm_id                |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | location_id    | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_diff_pfx03 |    1696410 |          20 | location_id,itm_id,id             |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | location_id    | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | n_leaf_pages |       1830 |        NULL | Number of leaf pages in the index |
| TestDB        | itm_location  | location_id    | 2022-11-24 18:59:19 | size         |       2148 |        NULL | Number of pages in the index      |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+---------------------+--------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------------------+
16 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [TestDB]> SHOW CREATE TABLE itm_location;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| itm_location | CREATE TABLE `itm_location` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `itm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `location_id ` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `combo` (`itm_id`,`location_id`),
  KEY `location_id` (`location_id`,`itm_id `) USING BTREE,
  KEY `qty ` (`qty `),
  CONSTRAINT `itm_location_itm` FOREIGN KEY (`itm_id `) REFERENCES `itm` (`itm_id `) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `itm_location_location` FOREIGN KEY (`location_id`) REFERENCES `locations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=61122082 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Why are you tagging both MySQL and MariaDB? These are different products. Which one are you using?

Comment: Using MariaDB 10.6.10

Comment: Okay, I have edited to clarify that. Keep in mind MariaDB forked from MySQL in 2010, and both products have been changing gradually since then. There are now many features that are incompatible, so don't think of them as variants of the same product.

Comment: Please show (in text, not images) an example of the two stats, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.

Comment: updated with details